# Printing lexicographically sorted subsets from a given string

Tags: algorithm, sorting, combinatorics

For ex - If the string is "abc", the answer should be 
a ab abc ac b bc c (Only lexicographically smallest combination from a set of characters should appear)
I have solved the problem but for string containing 15 or more characters, it is taking a lot of time. How can I reduce running time of my algorithm?
Here , n is length of string.
Here is my code:

```
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var str = Console.ReadLine();
            string coll = string.Empty;
            coll = coll + " " + str[0];
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                var items = coll.Split(' ');
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    coll = coll + " " + item+str[j];
                }
            }
            var tt = coll.Split(' ').OrderBy(a => a);
            foreach (var item in tt)
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: But `a ab abc ac b bc c` is not sorted on length?

Comment: what does your code do?

Comment: Edited the question for a better understanding. If the input string is abcd, the answer should be                                                                    a
ab
abc
abcd
abd
ac
acd
ad
b
bc
bcd
bd
c
cd
d

Comment: This code prints all possible combinations of letters of a given string S. If there are two strings with the same set of characters, print the lexicographically smallest arrangement of the two strings

Comment: Do you mean subsets? The title of your question is misleading.

Comment: Yes kraskevich, I have edited the title

Comment: There are an anful lot of combinations for a string of length 15, so it might be quite natural for your algorithm to take rather long.

Comment: Yes, but still I wanted to know if there is a scope of considerable improvement

Answer (score 1):

For a string of length n, there are 2^n possible subsets.  If each of the subsets needs to be printed, you can't get around the exponential complexity.

Comment: still there are some solutions that are better than others , it would be interesting to  see the suggestions